# Where can I declare custom initialization for custom table cells?

Tags: objective-c

If I have a custom table cell that is used by:

```
tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
```

Where inside of that custom cell can I set up custom initialization parameters? The auto-generated .m file for my custom table cell included:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    NSLog(@"INITWITHSTYLE!");
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

I added the `NSLog` call to see if that `initWithStyle` is ever called, but that `NSLog` is never reached, which means that that particular `initWithStyle` is also never called. So when a custom table cell is initialized using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, which `init` method of that custom cell is actually used?

Answer (score 1):

Your cell will get initialized once in `-(void)awakeFromNib` (even when it's from a Storyboard).

Then, there's no way to know where it will be dequeued, but it can receive a message when it's removed from screen and enqueued to the reusable cells pool: at this time `- (void)prepareForReuse` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard you can use awakeFromNib, otherwise the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` should be called

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
}
```

But you should remember that the cell will be reused so let's say if your cell is called first time `awakeFromNib` is called but later on the cell could be reused and this method won't be called again, it this scenario, if it doesn't work for you, you can use custom setter when you pass the data

//Extended

In comment you asked what method is called when the cell is reused.
You can use `prepareForReuse`, please read discussion (taken from Apple)

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
```

> Discussion If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a
>   reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is
>   returned from the UITableView method
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For performance reasons, you
>   should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to
>   content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table
>   view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always
>   reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not
>   have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you
>   override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass
>   implementation.

Comment: What method is called when a cell is "reused" then?

Comment: @user1806716 please see extended answer.